# Using Mean Function for a specified part of column of a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, statistics, mean

I am very new to R Programming,

I am triyng to calculate the mean of `z[1]` and keeping `70=<z[2]<=72` by the way

`z[1]` includes NA s.

I try this

```
 mean([z[1]!is.na(z[1])]& 70 =<z[2]<= 72)
```

but does not work.

If you help me , I would really appreciate.

Thanks

Comment: It is better to show some example datasets.  BTW, you need to check the `brackets`, ie `[z[1]`  Also, if it is a matrix as stated, `z[1]` will give just one element and not a column and there are other problems in the code `[1]!is.na`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need

```
mean(z[,1][70 <= z[,2] & z[,2] <= 72], na.rm=TRUE)
```

#### data

```
set.seed(45)
z <- matrix(sample(c(NA,70:80), 5*10, replace=TRUE), ncol=5, nrow=10)
```